# Outputs the same value even though tag names has different values in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm iterating on every element(post) on an array and each HTML tag name has a value of post._id. In the DOM, the outputs has different values as excepted but when I try to capture those values on the react Profile component, the console.log(el) outputs the same value for every different click of the elements in the DOM.

I have a links on every post on the profile, and when onClick event occurs on every link, I'm trying for each of them to have the id I gave to the tag name (post._id)

[image]

```
function handleReplyTweet(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        appDispatch({
            type: 'openReply',
        });
        let el = document.getElementById('reply').name;
        console.log(el);
        setTweetId(el);
        console.log(tweetId);
    }
```

HTML

```
tweetsData
                    .map((post, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index} className="main-view__user-feed">
                                <img src={post.avatar} alt="image tweet"></img>
                                <div className="main-view__user-feed__author">
                                    <div className="name">
                                        <h2>
                                            {post.name} {post.surname}
                                        </h2>
                                        <a href="#" className="username__author">
                                            @{post.username}
                                        </a>
                                        <span> 9 June</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <Link
                                        to={`/status/${post._id}`}
                                        className="author_post-viewpost"
                                    >
                                        {post.text}
                                    </Link>
                                    <div className="icons">
                                        <section>
                                            <li className="top-nav__item top-nav__item--active">
```

// Tyring to capture the names here from the DOM.

```
<Link
                                                        id="reply"
                                                        to={''}
                                                        onClick={handleReplyTweet}
                                                        className="top-nav__link"
                                                        name={post._id}
                                                    >
                                                        <svg className="top-nav__icon">
                                                            <use xlinkHref="img/sprite.svg#icon-bubble2"></use>
                                                        </svg>
                                                        <span>{post.comments.length}</span>
                                                    </Link>
                                                </li>
                                            </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the element in `react` (like input value etc) it is better to use `useRef` hook. But in your case you don't need to use it.

You can simply pass a function in `onClick` and call `handleReplyTweet` function from there with post id.

Hope below code sample I created for you helps:

https://playcode.io/926104/